# Crash when I try to alloc a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, alloc

Hi I am at my wits end with what I am doing wrong here. Has anyone experienced anything similar? I checked the apple developer forums, google, stack overflow and couldn't find anything.

```
MyViewController *myView;
myView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
//or myView = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
UIPopoverController *popover;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myView];  //always crash at here
//i've tried with some others ViewController but it's still crash.
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: What error are you getting? Remember that you can't use popover controllers on iPhone.

Comment: :D i'm developing on iPad,thanks Alexsander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're developing for iPad, try to give the `popOver` some frames, and try also to resize `MyViewController` nib, otherwise when it tries to load the view, it can't 'cause it's too big!

Something like

```
CGSizeMake(MyViewController.view.frame.size.width, MyViewController.view.frame.size.height);
```

Remember to resize it though